# Difference of one array key and second array value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have two arrays:

**First Array**

```
[
    'Test' => 1, 
    'Test2' => 2, 
    'Test3' => 3,
    ...
]
```

**Second Array**

```
[
    '0' => 'Test', 
    '1' => 'SomeTest',
    ...
]
```

I want to get difference of first array keys and second array values.

**Result Array**

```
[
    'Test2' => 2, 
    'Test3' => 3
]
```

Comment: And what's the question? "I want to" is __not__ a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$firstArray = [
    'Test' => 1, 
    'Test2' => 2, 
    'Test3' => 3
];

$secondArray = [
    '0' => 'Test', 
    '1' => 'SomeTest'
];

$result = array_diff($firstArray, array_flip($secondArray));

print_r($result);
exit;
```